What distances for plus and minus eyeglasses? Which are for middle distance?
My eyes can see fine close up and until about a foot or two distance from my face; after that, things begin to blur, such that the farthest distances are most blurred.
An eye doctor gave me a prescription with a plus power and a minus power. As I understand, the minus is to aid my vision for objects in the distance, and the plus is for close-up.
But I don’t need help with close distances. I need help with mid-distances (such as for reading a computer screen three feet from my face), and with far distances (such as for driving).
Which prescription is for mid-distance objects? Or was I given the wrong measurements?

I believe reading a screen from 3 feet would be considered close up. I've been wearing non-prescription reading glasses for a number of years for reading both paper and a computer. The same glasses work fine for both.
